# Difference between Compress and Clean method in Django Form Fields

Tags: django, custom-fields

I'm writing a custom date field for Credit Card Expiration Fields. I've noticed that in custom field examples, there are two major part that we need to override, clean and compress methods.

I know that we can validate and change return values of the field value in clean method. But what about compress method ? Why do we need that and what's the difference in between of clean and compress method ?

Answer (score 2):

`compress` only exists for subclasses of [`MultiValueField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/fields/#multivaluefield). As the documentation there explains, you use it in place of `clean` to convert the multiple values (one for each field) into a single value.

For every other type of field, you use `clean`.